# OpenCV C# iterate Mat object like C++

Tags: c#, c++, opencv, matrix

I'm trying to follow a tutorial of OpenCV which is written in C++ but I need to write it in C#. This works quite ok so far.
As I'm not a C++ developer and not. familiar with the language I came to a point now where I struggle a bit and where I'm not sure if what I did is the equivalent to the C++ version.

This is the code in C++

```
vector<Point> pointsOfInterest;
Mat_<uchar>::iterator itMask = mask.begin<uchar>();
Mat_<uchar>::iterator end = mask.end<uchar>();
for( ; itMask!=end; ++itMask)
    if(*itMask==255)
        pointsOfInterest.push_back(itMask.pos());
```

What I read here is a loop, that iterates over the whole Mat and checks if the value at position is 255 and if so, it adds the point to the end of the pointsOfInterest list.

So I guess this means every x,y pixel in the Mat is checked for the value. My equivalent in C# looks like this:

```
List<Point> pointsOfInterest = new List<Point>();
for(int x = 0;x<mask.Cols;x++)
{
    for(int y=0;y<mask.Rows; y++)
    {
        if (mask.At<int>(x, y) == 255)
            pointsOfInterest.Add(new Point(x, y));
    }
}
```

but the result I'm getting is not as expected that's why I wonder if this part is really correct? Sometimes the mask.At throws a NullPointer as well which is strange. I'm also wondering that the C++ just iterates a one dimensional array (I think at least) meanwhile C# would need 2-Dimensions.

Can someone confirm that it is the same or does someone know what is wrong and needs to be adjusted?

Comment: Is `mask` enumerable? Of the top of my head here, try replacing the two for loops with a foreach (in a very high-level sense, something similar is happening in C++ as well). It may even be more efficient then calling `.At<int>(x, y)`. The only problem is how to obtain the position, but maybe that's handled by the enumerator type in C#.

Comment: Thanks for your fast input :)
mask is of type Mat and unfortunately Mat is not enumerable :/

Comment: BTW, what are you using? Emgu CV? What is the type of `mask`? Are there online docs? It could also help us if you provided the link to the tutorial. EDIT: Just saw your comment - written this before that.

Comment: mask is of type Mat.
The tutorial I can not post because in fact it is a book :D
I'm using Unity and this asset https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/opencv-plus-unity-85928 for OpenCV

Comment: OK, according to that page, the OpenCV library this unity asset was based on was [this](https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp), and this is the source for the [Mat class](https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp/blob/a0d61065240eada9706fb2df2bf7ea5ce8f599d7/src/OpenCvSharp/Modules/core/Mat/Mat.cs). Here are the [docs](https://shimat.github.io/opencvsharp_docs/html/7b686c13-aaa7-5f3a-e2be-7da57895443f.htm), but they aren't very helpful.

Comment: However, it seems that it's roughly a 1-to-1 mapping, and in the OpenCV (C++) docs for [mat::at](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.3/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#ac40425b84f60b39fd35e03814122661f), it says that the parameters are `(int row, int col)`, in other words - (y, x). Maybe that's the problem - maybe that's why you are getting the NullReferenceException.

Comment: Yes true, switching x and y will solve the NullReference issue. However now mask.At always returns 1, perhaps that is correct and I did something wrong before I'l check that, thanks so far

Comment: The "mask" terminology and the fact that you are looking for 255 makes me think you are doing something with images; often, when color channels are expressed as floating point values, the range is [0, 1] - so if there's any spot where you are converting pixels from float to int, check what's happening there.

Answer (score 0):

I have also found out that changing the x and y, for the img.At(y,x) , will solve the exception and you will get the points in your list.